# WinServer Connects To SMB Share As "TINA2"

Tags: samba, network-share, hostname, netbios

I have a computer that has a fileshare (Windows Server 2012).  When I looked at the sessions, I saw a computer named `tina2`.  There is no current computer on our network named `tina2`.  When I investigated, it turns out that the computer shown as tina2 is in fact `GRE-V-QS02` (Windows Server 2016).

For some reason, GRE-V-QS02 is masquerading on the fileshare as tina2.

Does anyone know what could be going on?  I've checked the control panel, and the computer name is correct.

How do I get GRE-V-QS02 to stop showing up as tina2 in the `Shared Folders > Sessions` list.

Any helps is greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Really strange one... have you tried to access the Computer Management console from another computer and check if the displayed name is the correct one?

Comment: ...and you might try going to gre-v-qs02 and search through the registry for "tina2". Another thought, look in DNS and see if there is a record for that name, the name could be assigned the same ip address as the server. Could be some round-robin thing going on. One more, does "tina2" have an AD account?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a DNS issue.  The Forward Lookup Zone has one value(GRE-V-QS02), and the Reverse Lookup Zone has another (tina2).

[image]

[image]

The computer of Tina2 has not been on the network in years, so this problem is most likely a byproduct of not cleaning up the AD system.  Thanks for yalls help.

Comment: It's a byproduct of not cleaning up DNS. Turn on ageing and scavenging.